# admob banner not showing in popup

Tags: android, popup, admob, adsense, banner

I want add a banner following popup player of my android music player. In Android studio preview mode i have no error and it run fine but the banner is not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0">


<RelativeLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        tools:text="Mr.Afghani" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:src="@mipmap/play" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:src="@mipmap/pause"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/media_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playback_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|top"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                tools:text="00:00" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/bannerAd1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In mainActivity my code is correct i suppose because i tried putting banner in other screen and it worked fine. Is there any way to put banner in popup screen?

My code in MainActivity is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);



    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1234");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reasons for ads not showing in dialogs/pop-ups is due the banner ad not getting enough room (width) to show. 
Remember the ad sizes:

```
320x50      Standard Banner        Phones and Tablets   BANNER
320x100     Large Banner           Phones and Tablets   LARGE_BANNER
300x250     IAB Medium Rectangle   Phones and Tablets   MEDIUM_RECTANGLE
468x60      IAB Full-Size Banner   Tablets              FULL_BANNER
728x90      IAB Leaderboard        Tablets              LEADERBOARD
Screen      width x 32|50|90       Smart Banner     Phones and Tablets  SMART_BANNER
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

So since you're using the `Banner` ad size, make sure you pop-up has at least a width size of 320 to enable show the ad. If you it does have enough room and the ad still doesn't show, the problem could be a fill rate issue, meaning there's no ad to serve in your location. Let me know if this helps

**UPDATE:**

In the `onCreate()` method, you can set the width of the dialog to cover device screen's full width:

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        // int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.99); //99 percent
        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        if(isLandscape)
            getWindow().setLayout((int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.70), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        else getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can always check the logs in android studio to see if the issue is the banner size

Comment: Thanks Nana, But still the same problem. Edited the posted question as you said. have a look please.

Comment: @myads mail what you have done is set the width of the layout which won't have any effect on the dialog itself. Use match_parent  for the width and test in landscape mode to see if it works

Comment: @myadsmail yes, the layout isn't the issue.. it's the dialog theme. See my updated answer

Comment: i have added my MainActivity code also in my post. Could you check that please?

Comment: Yes sir, its the same no changes :(